# How do I bind a button to another xml file?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm creating my first mobile app and I'm trying to bind a button to go straight to another xml file. It seems like such an easy answer but I can't find the solution anywhere. I'm using Eclipse as my IDE and using the Android ADT bundle, if that's at all relevant.

Comment: Do you mean how to go to another activity from a button click?

Comment: Yes. Perhaps my question was worded poorly. I'm trying to have my submit button go to another xml page.

Basically, the question should have been "How do I bind a button to another xml file?"

It's been a long day. Lol.

Comment: If you wanted to go to another activity (which is a java file, the xml just takes care of the layout), then see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking how to create a layout with button that brings different layout? If so, you can drag button on your layout and put method in the "On Click" property of the button, something like myClick and then in your code add method

```
public void myClick(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MyNewActivity.class));
}
```

Make sure to declare new activity in AndroidManifest

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Put this in onCreate:

```
findViewById(R.id.my_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class))
    }
});
```

Replace my_button with the id of your button and MainActivity.this with the name of your main activity class.this and OtherActivity with the name of your other activity.class.

Comment: Would I have to import anything to get this to work?

Comment: you have to import `android.os.Intent`

Answer (score 0):

In your xml file, add this line of code to your button:

```
<Button>
    //other button properties here
    android:onClick='onNextPage'
</Button>
```

and in the activity/java file for that page, do this:

```
private void onNextPage(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, nextActivity.java);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

when you click the button, you'll go to nextActivity.java or whatever you named your second page to be.